# Reset 3d movieclip back to 2d movieclip

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I used the 3d transform tool to rotate and move an mc in 3d.
How do i make it to behave as a 2d movie again... Reset doesn't work... it only resets all to 0 but it's still 3d.
The only way I found was to delete it and drag it back from the library but is there a more common solution?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Remove Transform button at the bottom right side of the Transform Panel:
[image: Remove Transform]

In actionscript, set the matrix3D property of the MovieClip to null:

```
yourClip.transform.matrix3D = null;
```

Comment: Awesomeness :) 
For some reason it didn't cross my mind to look in the transform panel and I thought the Properties panel should have it as well :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw, you can aso use Shift+CMD+Z on OSX or Ctrl+Shift+Z on Windows :)